# Run Code In Worksheets Class Code Module In Another Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

This code is in a Workbook. ( In a Worksheets Class code Module )

```
Sub Testie()
Dim FullPathAndName As String
 Let FullPathAndName = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm'"
 Application.Run Macro:=FullPathAndName & "!FrmProTypeIn", Arg1:=42
End Sub
```

In another Workbook, named “NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm”, which is in the same Folder, I have this code, (in a Normal Code Module):

```
Sub FrmProTypeIn(MyArg As Long)
 MsgBox prompt:="Got Here :). The answer is " & MyArg & " , I forgot the question"
End Sub
```

If I run the first code, it makes the second code run , ( which tells me I got there and that the answer is 42, I forgot the question )

I would prefer to have the code, FrmProTypeIn() , (which is currently in a Normal Code Module)  to be in a Worksheets Code Module. The Worksheet Name is “FoodsLookUpTable”. The Worksheet Code Name is “Tabelle11”

Is this possible and can you give me the syntax?

If that is not possible, what about a simple work around? – The obvious thing I can think of is to have a Call ing code in a normal Module in Workbook “NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm” thus:

```
Sub CallFrmProTypeIn(MyArg As Long)
 Application.Run Macro:=Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(MyArg)
End Sub
```

Then I modify the first code slightly to this:

```
Sub Testies2()
Dim FullPathAndName As String
 Let FullPathAndName = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm'"
 Application.Run Macro:=FullPathAndName & "!CallFrmProTypeIn", Arg1:=42
End Sub
```

That workaround works. But maybe there is a simpler way?

Comment: did you try `Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Application.Run Macro:=Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(MyArg)`?

Comment: I didn't but I just did. Works great. Thanks. Alan

Comment: @Rory   Hi  Peh, I noticed whilst experimenting that your solution only works if the Workbook with the code being called has in it is open. So it suggests that Application.Run is working on the active Workbook if the Workbook is not specified in the Macro:= argument. ...   Having Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm") before Application seems to have no effect. But thanks again. Your solution along with the others and further comment replies has helped me understand this. I am writing a Summary solution. Alan

Comment: EDIT: I meant to say:...."..... your solution only works if the Workbook with the code being called has in it is the Active Workbook...." ( and also it only works when the Workbook with the code being called  in it is open..But  explain that in my Summary answer further  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarising for Prosperity: ( Subject to Edits based on any correcting comments. ;) )

It seems that you can call an Excel code routine ( including those in a Worksheets Class code Module )  from another Workbook. You can pass any optional or required arguments to the called routine.

The documentation is not too clear, or does not explain all, or is wrong..

Using the same example, I can ..

_1) do a simple Call

```
Call Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(42)
Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn 42
```

_2) There is an Application.Run Method.

_2a) But I suggest that this code line, although it “works” , probably does not get a chance to use it..

```
 Macro:=Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(42)
```

I say this as I could just as well do this and it “works” also

```
Dim vTemp As IBlogPictureExtensibility
 Let vTemp = Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(42)
```

I expect in the latter I did not get a chance  to extend the ability to Extensivibly Blog a Picture as the evaluation set off by the = did an auto intensively initiation of the code as I accidently exposed it at the VB Component ( Tabelle11 ) interface, which pseudo made the Object in a pseudo late binding type stylio

This works also

```
       If Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(42) Then MsgBox prompt:="It wasn't, but it did, so then perhaps was, was but too late - and then ....  like did an auto intensively initiation of the routine as I accidently exposed it at the VB Component ( Tabelle11 ) interface, which pseudo made the Object in a pseudo late binding type stylio. It was not Late, it came too late"
```

Maybe we could refer to the above as a “pseudo” Run Method, way to Run, or Run way

_2b)  Aplication.Run “StringReferrenceToMacroName”, MacroArgument1, MacroArgumet2, .....
I think this is using the Application.Run Method correctly; I believe this is wired to take a string reference to the string name of a macro, and also  any arguments therefor. The basic syntax therefore  would be

```
 Application.Run Macro:="'NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm'!Tabelle11.FrmProTypeIn", Arg1:=42
```

It is important here not to confuse, as I did, a code bit like  Tabelle11.FrmProTypeIn with the last string part in that last string,  which is the macro name. This macro Name can be seen, for by example, by hitting Alt+F8 to list the literal names of macros
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFnkb.jpg

An interesting advantage of using the Application.Run Method is that the string reference may be extended to  include the full path to the Workbook. This has no effect if the Workbook is open. If however, the Workbook is closed, then the workbook is opened by a code line of this form:

```
 Application.Run Macro:="'H:\ALERMK2014Marz2016\NeueBlancoAb27.01.2014\AbJan2016\OutlineGrouping\RoryAppRun\NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm'!Tabelle11.FrmProTypeIn", Arg1:=42
```

_.....

A few last notes:

_A)  These two codes are in fact doing the same thing:

```
 Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Application.Run Macro:=Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(42)
 Application.Run Macro:=Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(42)
```

They only work if Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm") is Active. This suggests that Application.Run with unqualified Workbook will go to the Active Workbook. I think that this is one of those occasions showing us that VBA is not really a Object Orientated Programming language. The Application can be called at various levels , but effectively goes “back up” the Hierarchy, so the use of Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm") has no effect. 
Similarly , if “ProAktuellex8600x2.xlsm” is my workbook with the code in it, ( or any other open workbook for that matter ), then this will still work

```
 Workbooks("ProAktuellex8600x2.xlsm").Application.Run Macro:=Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(42)
```

The important part is the

```
 Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(42)
```

_ B) use of Run appears to default to Application.Run

_C ) We do not appear to have a Workbooks or Worksheets Run in such a way as we have , for example, a Worksheets Evaluate in addition to an Application Evaluate. This explains why  ...Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Application.Run Macro:=Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(42) ... is “ignoring” the Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm")

Comment: At Alan. Hi. Consider it similar to like the Range(“ “) “Method”. You build a string “ “ there, and can use VBA variables to build that string. Similarly the .Run method takes a string. It will accept therefore something like Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(42) expecting to take that as part of a final string reference. As you demoed, before it gets a chance to finish that string, you accidentally expose the interface of the class module which is what you would do to apply via the way you do  a Call of the routine. There is no Application.Run Wb.Ws.MyMacro(42) type Method

Comment: At Alan.... I am further thinking that the Range(" ") does something like just adding the missing bit to the full path reference. So it evokes an  exposing at interface of the class of a Range object causing a sort of auto instancing so that you can do a fairly late ish auto instancing of the Range object, allowing it to be used as object. . Defining a Range variable can be thought of as Early Binding. As with .Run it converts the string reference to the OOP code line chain.. ... It is al starting to fall into place nicely... :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax would be:

```
Let FullPathAndName = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm'"
 Application.Run Macro:=FullPathAndName & "!Sheet1.FrmProTypeIn", Arg1:=42
```

Comment: @ RoryAhhhh!-Brilliant, thanks, that is what I was getting close to and looking for. :) ;)
Let FullPathAndName = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm'"
 Application.Run Macro:=FullPathAndName & "!Tabelle11.FrmProTypeIn", Arg1:=42
I thank you sir!
Alan

Comment: What threw me off, and why I almost, but did not quite get the solution from Rory, is having a . Dot in a String reference. I am not sure how I feel about that...  like in a Named Range scoped to a different Worksheet, I get this ( with the sheet reference added by VBA if I do not give it ) Sheet2!MyNamedRange. ...   But a . Dot in a string reference doing something is weird. I actually had your solution almost: I had like Application.Run Macro:=FullPathAndName & "!Tabelle11!FrmProTypeIn", Arg1:=42

Comment: So Tabelle11 is the Code Name of my Worksheet.... That is an Object variable??.. In code this.. Tabelle11.FrmProTypeIn ... is applying the Method Property Code FrmProTypeIn of Tabelle11............But I do not expect to see that in a literall String. ... I would expect to see the Name  ... "FoodsLookUpTable" ... in a literal string...   ?????

Comment: That's not really a question, but the code is in the VBComponent, and the name of the component is Tabelle11, not whatever you see on the tab.

Comment: I am getting no Email Notifications from Stack overflow.. Never mind, thanks for replying....I forgot the question. ....   I understand that Tabelle11 is not the tab name... But in a code ( in same workbook  as Tabelle11 ), ..  I can do  like ..Call Tabelle11.FrmProTypeIn …. So FrmProTypeIn is a Method code Property of the Object Worksheet „FoodLookUpTable“ / Tabelle11 …

Comment: It’s not really a question, but .....   My concern is using the code snippet ...  Tabelle11.FrmProTypeIn .. in a literal expression.  ....  maybe it shouldn’t be ....    or maybe it shouldn’t be.. my concern

Comment: `FrmProTypeIn` is a method, *not* a property. It is a method exposed by the Tabelle11 class (interface), which is auto-instantiating and can therefore be referred to directly as an object..

Comment: ....”...It is a method exposed by the Tabelle11 class (interface), which is auto-instantiating and can therefore be referred to directly as an object..   ..’_  ʅ_(ツ)_ʃ     …  ¯\(ツ)/¯  _ :) ;)”... That sounds arousingly nice.WETF it means. :)  ..... So it could be said to be an object...  I am not sure it follows from that it can be used as an object.   .....  It seems to be an object...

Comment: Question: Is the thing that can be said to be an object, the  same object returned from the Worksheets(   )  thing which returns  an object when taking the string „FoodLookUpTable“ as an argument  ????…. Or is the Latter an object, and the former an auto-instanting like version and like would( could ) .. Worksheets(“FoodsLookUpTable”).Something ... and ... Tabelle11.Something   ... do / give different results.. ???

Comment: I remembered the question   .. WTF   is code snippet... Tabelle11.FrmProTypeIn   ... doing in a string reference type literal string ???

Comment: `Run` takes the *name* of a routine, hence it's a string. Nothing weird there. Re the earlier question, its the same object. `TypeOf Tabelle11 Is Worksheet` and `TypeOf Sheets(“FoodsLookUpTable”) Is Tabelle11` should both return true.

Comment: OK ;)  .... I guess I was just expecting a name type syntax of...like...!Tabelle11* ʅ_(ツ)_ʃ *FrmProTypeIn ....  with  anything  in place of * ʅ_(ツ)_ʃ *   .. rather than a Dot which made me thhink it was a code snippet.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Edit, P.s.   I was not thinking of different type so much as different way of working like in Late or Early biinding of the same object

Comment: Run isn't binding at all really, but it would definitely be late as much as it is.

Comment: Thanks. ... Yeh, .. I always get the feeling it is Late, if anything,  when I am jogging....  same reasoning I guess... I sometimes need to run more and harder than dwelling too much on understanding.   .. But in the long runs ,..  I find it helps to ensure it works constantly healthily longer., .. ‘-_...

Comment: ....... So I think I almost have it... Part of the String has the actual Code line Call Argument String ( Macro:=ThisBit )  in it  it  needs in it. ..”.........ThisBit..........”   .. so that is for code in Normal  Module    “.....FrmProTypeIn……“        or  for Worksheets Class Code Module    “.....Tabelle11.FrmProTypeIn......”  The ! is just the bit to tell VBAA that the Call Augment is coming... ....  BUT  ‘_-...

Comment: BUT: ....Question:   Where this works:...   Application.Run Macro:=FullPathAndName & "!Tabelle11.FrmProTypeIn" ......  This does not work ... Application.Run Macro:=FullPathAndName & "!Worksheets(""FoodsLookUpTable"").FrmProTypeIn" .. ( and I do have the double quotes so that VBA sees    Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable") which I am assuming it sees as an equivalent of Tabelle11

Comment: It wouldn't. The first one uses the macro name as it would appear in the macros dialog. The second is trying to call VBA methods inside a string which won't work.

Comment: OK.. so that answers some question or other that I  had somewhere. .. So it is not the argument of the Call code line that is  in that string. It is the Name ( “macros dialog thingy name )  of the macro,...    I get it I think. A macro apparently has a name.  That is built up by.... “!” & “  TheCodeName & “DOT” & TheRoutineName .. So the point is, as I suggested, that it is an unfortunate and very misleading choice to use a DOT in that string build.

Comment: ....I checked: Instead of this  ...  Application.Run Macro:=FullPathAndName & "!Tabelle11.FrmProTypeIn", Arg1:="GoToDebiNet" ......  This will work instead: .... Application.Run Macro:=FullPathAndName & "!" & Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").CodeName & "." & "FrmProTypeIn", Arg1:="GoToDebiNet" .... ( well it was obvious actually, I am just building the same string..  )

Comment: ....One thing which is a shame.. I cannot always use that last  long Explicitly Pedantic code line ...  This because  as a nice side effect of Application.Run , It opens the file “NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm” if it is not already. But if the File is not open, then I cannot use the Workbooks Collection object of open Files to get at the code name from  ..... Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").CodeName

Comment: .....  So I would need to somehow get at a Worksheets Code Name  in a closed Workbook. ....  I once got at the Worksheet Name, or rather my Wife did ,. bless him, .   https://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/1144844-copy-range-values-from-closed-workbook-from-any-worksheet-item.html   ...  so I will ask her if she could do the same to get me the Code Name... I have no idea why I should want to do all this .. so I will probably do it next week, when I get a Mo..

Comment: Hi. I have added a Summarising solution. If you have time to review, I would be grateful of any comments. And thanks again for your comments , which along with the other solution from Peh has helped ,  I think, me to get to the bum of this :)  Alan. ( Oh dear, I think messed up the code tags ..?? ?

Comment: ( I fixed the Code tags here, 'cause I could )

Answer (score 0):

@ Peh
Hi Peh
I had not tried that. That and variations of it do work . Great Thanks. I had been told that this was not possible as I was told that a code cannot be run from a Worksheets code module in another Workbook.
I am wondering if this is telling me that  technically I the code has become now a Property of the Worksheets Class module.
So the first three lines here are variations of your suggestion that work.
The last two are typical variation that I had been trying which do not work

```
 Sub PehTesties()
  Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Application.Run Macro:=Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(42)
  Application.Run Macro:=Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(42)
  Application.Run   Macro:=Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn(42)
  ' Application.Run Macro:=Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").FrmProTypeIn Arg1:=42
  ' Application.Run Macro:="'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm'!FoodsLookUpTable!CallFrmProTypeIn", Arg1:=42
  End Sub
```

Thanks once again
Alan

Comment: It's actually a method not a property.

Comment: I think I was meaning that it was a Property of the Worksheet, even thought it was a Method..:RolleyEyes: ??? .... Hm.. VBA being Pooy not OOP again.. Method of the Application or the Worksheet .... Application.Run Macro:=FullPathAndName & "!Tabelle11.FrmProTypeIn", Arg1:=42 ....
 Workbooks("NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm").Worksheets("FoodsLookUpTable").Application.Run Macro:=FullPathAndName & "!Tabelle11.FrmProTypeIn", Arg1:=42

Comment: So Stack Overflow is Poo? No notifications so none ever follows up and most answers never get seen? I applogise if I am wrong. But I certainly intend to expose a thing or two at an interface making it possible to refer to something as an object. Or go Late r about jogging instead. I thank you.

Comment: It works the way it works, not the way you do. Perhaps you need your own blog??

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for the reply. :)  I have had that suggestion before. I think my experience and involvement level in computing makes that inappropriate. For one thing too many bad people out there messing up and virusing people. I would be a good victim. I have a Partial solution in having permission to “Blog” a bit in some sites. But I mostly value the chance to get help from people like you. :) . Stack overflow, like anything I guess  needs getting used to. I’m encouraged you saw a reply. ...   Question: What do you do? – Periodically check this: http://imgur.com/OfhgBwT

Comment: I got some help from the help desk. They showed me how to search for just Excel / VBA stuff.  ....you can..... ”...  search for questions in those tags and sort them by newest to achieve somewhat the same effect.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba+or+excel-vba?sort=newest
.....”.... Do you do anything like that ?????

Comment: I expect it could be made to work the way I do.  I expect a code could be written to check periodically  that thing that shows comments and replies ..    But that is overdoing it for my low level involvement .. And I have got a long way to knowing all I  need to know, thanks to a large extent from help from people like you ... :) .. To a large extent I am just tidying up currently and solving a few basic problems that no one had sussed out yet... or got wrong  ... ;)    :)